# Is each timestamp in the iPhone Messages app its own cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, chat

I'm building an [open source version of the native iPhone Messages app called AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat). Each message is represented by a `UITableViewCell` with the timestamp at the top of the cell and the message below it.

Now, I'm implementing conditional timestamps, i.e., only show the timestamp for a message if that message is the first cell or if it's been 15 minutes since the last timestamp shown.

When I go into edit mode for a conversation in the iPhone Messages app, it looks like each timestamp is its own cell. I'd like to do the same because eventually, I'd like to add edit mode support too.

1. So then, based on the `indexPath`, how will I know whether to return a timestamp or a message cell?
2. I'm using an `NSFetchedResultsController` for the messages. So, how do I keep track of the number of timestamps I've shown before a certain message so that I can use this as an offset when calling `Message *msg = [fetchedResultsController_ objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, after making the `fetchRequest` for `Message` objects, iterate through the results and create an `NSMutableArray *cellMap`, which you should also make an ivar. Set each element of `cellMap` to `currentTimestamp` or `message`, depending on the `previousTimestamp`.

Check out the [ChatViewController](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat/blob/master/Classes/ChatViewController.m#L166-172) of [AcaniChat](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat) for the solution.

Comment: @Matt i'm in the boat as you were couple of years ago, i liked your answer however, i need to know, currently, when i get new message, NSFetchedResultController updates my table through delegates. how is it going to work if i use NSMutableArray and use that for TableView delegate/datasource?