# UITableView don't float section headers

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Is it possible to not float the section headers for a `UITableView` with style `UITableViewStylePlain`?

I'm building [AcaniChat, an open-source version of iPhone's native Messages app](https://github.com/acani/AcaniChat), and I want to make the timestamps section headers, but they shouldn't float.

I know that section headers don't float for table views of style `UITableViewStyleGrouped`, but that style looks less like what I'm going for. Should I just use that style and restyle the table view to make it look how I want?

I might do that if I can figure out how to make https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564712/nsfetchedresultscontroller-nsdate-section-headers.

Comment: i think a viable implementation will be using a different kind of cell for the timestamps

Comment: [I've done this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561688/is-each-timestamp-in-the-iphone-messages-app-its-own-cell), but it gets complicated because I'm using an `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the message cells. How would you insert the timestamp cells into the fetched results? I created a mutable array to do this, but then I loose the benefits of `NSFetchedResultsController`, right? And, if you think about it conceptually, the timestamps are more like section headers than cells because the messages are being grouped, or *sectioned*, by their `sentDate`.

Comment: yes, you lose the benefits of `NSFetchedResultsController` if you change to cells for timestamps - - - if the time stamps are more conceptually like headers, then you'd want them to float; you are losing that information about visible cells if they don't float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess either you will have to use two kinds of custom tableCells or skip the tableview entirely and work on a plain scrollview to achieve this kind of style.

Answer (score 2):

The interesting thing about UITableViewStyleGrouped is that the tableView adds the style to the **cells** and not to the TableView.

The style is added as backgroundView to the cells as a class called UIGroupTableViewCellBackground which handles drawing different background according to the position of the cell in the section.

So a very simple solution will be to use UITableViewStyleGrouped, set the backgroundColor of the table to clearColor, and simply replace the backgroundView of the cell in cellForRow:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

This can now be done in two quick and easy steps (iOS 6 only):

1. Change your UITableView style to UITableViewStyleGrouped. (You can do this from Storyboard/NIB, or via code.)
2. Next, set your tableview's background view to a empty view like so [in either a method such as  *viewDidAppear*  or even in the  *cellForRow*  method (though I would prefer the former)].

> ```
> yourTableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:listTableView.bounds];
> ```

Voila, now you have your table view - but without the floating section headers. Your section headers now scroll along with the cells and your messy UI problems are solved!

This works because  UITableViewStyleGrouped  seems to now work by adding a background view to a plain UITableView, but without the floating section headers. 
[N.B. Earlier to iOS 6, individual background images were added to UITableViewCell's.]

Do try this out and let me know how it goes. 
Happy coding :)

EDIT: for iOS 7, simply change the table view style to '*UITableViewStyleGrouped*' and change the view's tint color to 'clear color'.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by putting the headers into their own sections.  First double your number of sections.  Then for the even-numbered sections, return your header as the header and zero as the number of rows.  For the odd-numbered sections, return nil for the header.

Assuming you're using an NSFetchedResultsController, it would look something like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count * 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ((section % 2) == 0)
    {
        section /= 2;

        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResults.sections[section];
        return sectionInfo.name;
    }
    else
    {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ((section % 2) == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        section /= 2;

        id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = self.fetchedResults.sections[section];
        return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ((indexPath.section % 2) == 0)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section/2];
        id object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // configure your cell here.
    }
}
```

Comment: because "they" don't try to understand what they can't comprehend easily. anyways... +1. will work although not a very standard way. similarly... another way would be to not have a section header and simply make the first row of every section appear as the header (handling the row count by adding 1 to offset the first row)

Comment: This is a cool solution, can be made to work with NSFetchedResultsController with minimal effort.